Why is my AJAX request not working in Node.js and Express project?
I'm trying to make a request using ajax to my backend, but it always returns a 404 error, but my route exists.
Project structure:
public
-scripts
--script.js
routes
-chats.js
views
-chats.ejs
index.js
Index.js (My port is 3000):
//...
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config();

//Express instance
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT;

//Mongoose instance
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
.then(() => console.log('Connected to MongoDB'))
.catch(err => console.error('Could not connect to MongoDB:', err));

//Body-parser instance
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//Express-session instance
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
}));

//Static-files instance & EJS 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Routers
const authenticationRouter = require('./routes/auth');
app.use("/auth", authenticationRouter);

const chatsRouter = require('./routes/chats');
app.use("/chats", chatsRouter);

// Routes
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("index");
});

//Express listener
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}.`));


script.js:
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#addFriendForm').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const friendName = $('#friendName').val();
        if (friendName === '') {
            $('#error-message').text('Usuário não encontrado.');
        } else {
            $('#error-message').text('');


            // Send AJAX request to add friend
            $.ajax({
                url: '/chats/addfriend',
                type: "post",
                method: 'POST',
                data: { friendName: friendName },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        const avatarUrl = `/path/to/avatars/${friendName}.png`; 
                        $('#friendsList').append(`
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center friend-item" data-friend-name="${friendName}">
                                    <img src="${avatarUrl}" alt="${friendName}" class="friend-avatar me-2">
                                    ${friendName}
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        `);
                        $('#friendName').val('');
                    } else {
                        $('#error-message').text(data.error);
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('Erro AJAX:', textStatus, errorThrown);
                    $('#error-message').text('Erro ao adicionar amigo. Tente novamente.');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

Console log:
POST http://localhost:3000/chats/addfriend 404 (Not Found)

chats.js:
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        if (!req.session.userId) {
            return res.redirect("/auth/login");
        }

        const currentUser = await User.findById(req.session.userId);
        
        const friendship = await Friendship.findOne({ user: currentUser._id }).populate('friends');

        const friendsList = friendship ? friendship.friends : [];

        const allUsers = await User.find().select('_id username nickname');

        return res.render('chats', { currentUser, friendsList, allUsers });

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).send('Erro interno do servidor');
    }
});

router.post('/addfriend', async (req, res) => {
    const { friendName } = req.body;

    try {
        const friend = await User.findOne({ username: friendName });
        if (!friend) {
            console.log('Não foi possível encontrar o usuário pelo nome de usuário', friendName);
            return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Usuário não encontrado.' });
        }

        const currentUser = await User.findById(req.session.userId);

        if (!currentUser || !currentUser.friends) {
            console.log('Não foi possível encontrar o usuário atual ou eles não têm amigos', currentUser);
            return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Usuário não encontrado ou amigos não inicializados.' });
        }

        currentUser.friends.push(friend._id);
        await currentUser.save();

        res.status(200).json({ success: true });

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Erro ao adicionar amigo. Tente novamente mais tarde.' });
    }
});

The funny thing is that if I change the route to the GET method and try to access it through my browser, it returns me correctly (200), but the route with the post method I cannot access via Ajax.
Apparently everything is correct with my request, but it doesn't work, does anyone have any idea why?

You tried the url /addfriend (rather than /chats/addfriend)?

@JoshWulf Yes, but this would result in the wrong route, the correct route is chats/addfriend. Anyway it doesn't just work with /addfriend, it still returns 404.

So why doesn't your route say /chats/addfriend?

@Daedalus no, my route is complete (and has a catch), it was just an example of how it is

@Phil the router.post('/addfriend', ...) is in chat.js wich linked by app.use("/chats", chatsRouter);, so the link is localhost:3000/chats/addfriend. The router is just const router = express.Router();

@Phil look, in the ajax has a catch, and always returns to me a $('#error-message').text('Erro ao adicionar amigo. Tente novamente.');. But in case of doubt, I edited the post again with the full /addfriend route, and i already use app.use(express.urlencoded()).

So you have two potential sources of a 404 response in your route handler. What debugging have you done to identify or rule out those as the cause? Some simple logging would be appropriate, eg console.log('Could not find user by username', friendName) and console.log('Could not find current user or they have no friends', req.session.userId, currentUser)

@Phil Even debugging the way you said, it doesn't even reach these debuggers, it always stops at the Ajax catch

Those console.log() suggestions are for your server-side code in the if (!friend) and if (!currentUser || !currentUser.friends) checks. You should also be able to see the message you send in the response in your browser's dev-tools Network panel

@Phil I edited the post with the updated code, returns: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) script.js:66 Erro AJAX: error Not Found

The result of those console.log() reports will not be shown in the browser. They will be in the terminal where you run your Express app

In your client-side code, try logging jqXHR.responseText as well

@Phil ooooh, now I understand, thank you very much, you returned the console.log with the MongoDB error!

And what was that error? A MongoDB error should trigger your catch which responds with a 500, not a 404

@Phil The log console returned me and along with a 404, I manipulated it so that this error is displayed on the page. (There was no schema called "Friendship" and much less any document in it, MongoDB gave an error), and the currentUser.friends didn't even exist, because the "friends" were in a separate schema from the "User" schema
